# heroku run returns "no route to host" error

Tags: heroku

I have a django project that is running on heroku.  I am able to run certain heroku commands, such as `heroku ps` and `heroku logs`.  When I try to use any `heroku run` commands, I get a `no route to host` error.

```
heroku run ls
Running ls attached to terminal... /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:33:in `initialize': No route to host - connect(2) (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
```

I am using chrome on a home wireless dsl connection, with no firewalls or anything on my end.

What can I do to use `heroku run`?

Comment: @neil I get the same exact error when I try `heroku run bash`.

Comment: I can run detached commands such as `heroku run:detached ls`, and then view the output by running `heroku logs`.  But that's a pretty inefficient workflow, and I'm not sure how many commands it will work for.  I tried running commands from another project directory, and I get the same result.

Comment: I haven't fixed this yet, but I'm pretty sure it's an issue with my modem.